# Tree Structure in JSP

Tags: jsp

I have a JSP file showing a tree structure. Each link opens another JSP in the same window.

I have used webFxItem to create the tree structure.

Here is the code that I have been using:

```
var tree = new WebFXTree('Supplier','supplier.jsp');
tree.setBehavior('classic');
var f = new WebFXTreeItem('Requests');
tree.add(f);
f.add(new WebFXTreeItem('Panels',   'request_panels.jsp'));
```

I need to pass parameters to request_panels.jsp. Is there any way to pass parameters/variables to the other jsp files in WebFXTreeItem.

Answer (score 0):

Provide Query Parameter to the jsp file.

```
f.add(new WebFXTreeItem('Panels',   'request_panels.jsp?sessionID=' + value));
```